# jQuery: show onclick works only for first button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have more buttons what will show content onclick. When someone click any button, all contents (toShow) may appear.
Currently it works but only on first button. So when someone click first button, all contents appear, but I need that all contents appear when someone click to any button on page. Maybe I need for cycle? Thanks for help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("toShow").hide();
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("toShow").show();
        $("buttonShow").hide();
    });
});

<h1>First element</h1>
<buttonShow>
<button id="show">show</button>
</buttonShow>

<toShow>
content
</toShow>

<h2>Second element</h2>
<buttonShow>
<button id="show">show</button>
</buttonShow>

<toShow>
content
</toShow>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you have multiple of the same id's. Assign classes instead, and for any button with class `.show` - the appropriate event handler will fire

```
<button class="show">show</button>
<button class="show">show</button>
<button class="show">show</button>
```

---

```
$('.show').click(function(){
    $('toShow').show();
    $('buttonShow').hide();
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7q4jekLt/)

Comment: @JackDavis np please remember to accept answer if you found this helpful so we can both gain a little rep

Comment: Sure, I am waiting because it says: "You can accept an answer in 5 minutes". :D